# What is 'Process I/O' in Process Explorer

Tags: process-explorer

I'm debugging a performance issue on an RDS server, and trying to understand the output of the System Information graphs in Process Explorer:

[image: System Information]

The I/O graph is showing about 40Mb/s total and the Network and Disk graphs are showing much less in aggregate. What other I/O is contributing to the Process I/O graph, is it memory I/O?